# Unable to set marker color in go.Bar (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am learning to code in Dash and for some odd reason I am unable to change the color of the bar chart in go.Bar. Both the background of the chart and the bar color don't seem to change. The tooltip however does take the color. It seems like a simple problem to solve but somehow I am stumped and clueless. I am using PyCharm on Mac.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')

# print(df.columns)

data = [go.Bar(x=df['Region'], y=df['Total Profit'], marker=dict(color='red'))]

layout = go.Layout(title="Region Profit")
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig)
```

This is what the df.head() looks like.

```
Region     Country  Item Type Sales Channel Order Priority Order Month  Total_Orders  Units_Sold  Avg_Cost  Total_Revenue  Total_Cost  Total_Profit
0   Asia  Bangladesh  Baby Food       Offline              C  2012-10-31             1        1298    159.42      331353.44   206927.16     124426.28
1   Asia  Bangladesh  Baby Food       Offline              C  2016-04-30             1        9136    159.42     2332238.08  1456461.12     875776.96
2   Asia  Bangladesh  Baby Food       Offline              H  2011-02-28             1        3972    159.42     1013972.16   633216.24     380755.92
3   Asia  Bangladesh  Baby Food       Offline              H  2011-11-30             1        4438    159.42     1132932.64   707505.96     425426.68
4   Asia  Bangladesh  Baby Food       Offline              H  2012-04-30             1        1811    159.42      462312.08   288709.62     173602.46
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: that is pretty strange – I have only seen that behavior happen if you try to plot one point and set the mode to `'lines'` which will confuse `plotly`. one thing is i notice is that the total profit indicated in the hovertemplate doesn't seem to match what's on the yaxis. can you share a sample of your `df` so we can try to reproduce your problem? you can paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question

Comment: I have included the df.head(). Does it look like an aggregation issue? Too many data points for the single region? But should it impact the styling attributes?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the provided data, but it is possible you have too many data points for each category. what happens if you zoom in?